# Why do assets that were compiled through laravel-mix not display the view correctly?

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I compiled all the assets correctly through Laravel-mix and just referenced a single compiled file but when I let it show, it doesn't correctly display. With laravel-mix: 
[image]

Without it:
[image]

> webpack.mix.js

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */


 mix.combine(['./resources/assets/lib/dashboard/vendors/bower_components/jasny-bootstrap/dist/css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css',
    './resources/assets/lib/dashboard/dist/css/style.css',
    './resources/assets/lib/dashboard/vendors/bower_components/dropify/dist/css/dropify.min.css'
    ],'./public/dist/css/auth.css')


 mix.combine(['./resources/assets/lib/dashboard/vendors/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    './resources/assets/lib/dashboard/vendors/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    './resources/assets/lib/dashboard/vendors/bower_components/jasny-bootstrap/dist/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js',
    './resources/assets/lib/dashboard/dist/js/jquery.slimscroll.js',
    './resources/assets/lib/dashboard/dist/js/dropdown-bootstrap-extended.js',  
    './resources/assets/lib/dashboard/dist/js/init.js',
    ],'./public/dist/js/auth.js')
```

Comment: paste the content of webpack.mix.js or gulpfile.js to check

Comment: @MohamedSabil83 added it in my question, sir

Comment: Oh, I forgot to copy all the necessary files like the icons. Ok

Comment: good to know. if not work tell us.